# It is possible to use bootstrap library only for the content without the header and the footer in 'thymeleaf'?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, thymeleaf

I would like to know whether it is possible to use the bootstrap library without influencing the footer and the header ? Is there any possibility? thank you in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
     >
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>

    <div th:replace="fragments/header1 :: header1-css"></div>
    <div th:replace="fragments/footer1 :: footer1-css"></div>
    <div th:replace="fragments/container :: container"></div>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../static/css/bootstrap.min.css" th:href="@{/css/bootstrap.min.css}"/>

</head>
<body>
<div th:replace="fragments/header1 :: header1">Header</div>


    <h1>
        Liste Utilisateurs

    </h1>


    <p><a th:href="@{rechercheMotcle}">chercher un utilisateur par mot Cle</a></p>


<div>
    <div class="col-md-12 col-md-offset-1">

        <div class="panel panel-default panel-table">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col col-xs-12">
                        <h3 class="panel-title">Administrateur</h3>
                    </div>
```

This bootstrap librairie affect my header also and I don't want that[image]

My navbar must be like that :
[image]